SQLAlchemy not executing full stored procedure
I'm using the following code to execute a SQL stored procedure from Python. The stored procedure in question iterates over a number of different insert statements contained in another table. However, when ran from Python, the stored procedure doesn't iterate over the complete set of data.
I've tested the stored procedure myself in SQL and it works fine. I've also tried editing the pool_timeout parameter on the sql_engine connection but that doesn't seem to change anything either.
How can I ensure that the below code continues until the entire stored procedure has been completed?
import connection_manager as cm
from sqlalchemy import text

sql_engine = cm.create_db_engine('Server','Database')    

with sql_engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(text("EXEC dbo.SomeStoredProcedure"))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close() 


For diagnostic purposes, try crsr = sql_engine.raw_connection().cursor() followed by crsr.execute("EXEC dbo.SomeStoredProcedure") and crsr.commit() to see if that behaves differently.

I've added if conn is not None: before conn.close() in the finally block to ensure that the connection is only closed if it was successfully created.
import connection_manager as cm
from sqlalchemy import text
import logging

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Create database engine
sql_engine = cm.create_db_engine('Server', 'Database')

try:
    with sql_engine.connect() as conn:
        logging.info("Executing stored procedure...")
        result = conn.execute(text("EXEC dbo.SomeStoredProcedure"))
        
        # Optionally fetch and log the result
        for row in result:
            logging.info(row)

        logging.info("Stored procedure executed successfully.")
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")
finally:
    conn.close()
    logging.info("Connection closed.")


There aren't any results, the stored procedure doesn't return anything. It just inserts data into a few different tables.

@unknown9192 see edit I made and see if that fixes it. Also check the logs out to see where in the process it gets stuck

The ‘stored procedure was executed successfully’ message was shown when running this.
I wondered if the stored procedure I execute, which in turn iterates over a number of values and executes a subsequent stored procedure was having an effect here?
Does it open a connection for each subsequent procedure which then reaches a limit?
